# Filebeat won't exclude line

Tags: filebeat

I have a Python process writing the following example JSON log line:

```
{"levelname": "DEBUG", "asctime": "2020-02-04 08:37:42,128", "module": "scale_out", "thread": 139793342834496, "filename": "scale_out.py", "lineno": 130, "funcName": "_check_if_can_remove_inactive_components", "message": "inactive_components: set([]), num_of_components_active: 0, max num_of_components_to_keep: 1"}
```

In the filebeat.yml, I'm trying to exclude all DEBUG logs from being sent into Elasticsearch.
I've tried using the `exclude_lines` keyword, but Filebeat still publish these events.

I've also tried using a `processor` with `drop event`

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/my_service/*.log

  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.message_key: "module"
  exclude_lines: ['DEBUG'] # also tried ['.*DEBUG.*']
  keep_null: true

processors:
 - drop_event:
     when:
        levelname: 'DEBUG'
```

Any ideas what am I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..
It was much more easier (and stupid) that I expected it to be.
While the exclude_lines doesn't work (still),
I was able to get the drop_event to work.

The problem was that the 'DEBUG' should had been written without quotes.

```
processors:
- drop_event:
    when:
      levelname: DEBUG
```